# Remove postback blink in an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, web-applications

I have a web project that uses one master page with five image buttons.  Each image button uses a click event that redirects to it's respective page.  For example,

```
Public Event Click As ImageClickEventHandler

Protected Sub btnHome_Click() Handles btnHome.Click
    Me.Response.Redirect("/Home.aspx")
End Sub
```

The issue is that almost everytime a button is clicked there is a blink when a page loads.

The blinking occurs in IE and Chrome, but not Firefox.  I've tried the following meta tags, in my master page, with no success.  I've used all of them, only the opacity, and the page-enter and exit without the opacity tag, and no success.  Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)"/>
<meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="blendTrans(Duration=0)"/>
<meta http-equiv="Page-Enter" content="Alpha(opacity=100)"/>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the "postback" blink? That's a normal behavior. The blink time is the time between the browser getting and rendering the HTML file.

Comment: Yes, but it's a very obvious blink that looks bad.

Comment: So, it's looking like an update panel may be the solution.  I've never used one before, can I add the panel to my master page, or do I need to add one to each child page?

Comment: Check my answer. Putting an update panel in your master would help but it will make your design much much more complex. You need to make each target page as a control (not a full page) and toggle it on/off depending on the buttons. That's not probably a good design. The update pane does what i said in my post. It is like AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be describing the **"postback" blink**. Unfortunately, there are multiple factors causing this blink. So when you press one image button, you send a request to the server, asking for a new HTML page. While the browser parses the HTML for rendering it, it might appear as blank.

This blink can be influenced by many factors:

- The client's network bandwidth
- The server's throughput capabilities
- The speed of the test computer
- The target page complexity
- The target page content size
- The target page embedded scripts

With the first 3 there's not much to do (except by paying for more :) ). You can work on optimizing the latter. You can check if you have very big images or embedded content that needs to be rendered, or complex initialization functions on the server/client side. An **update panel** also might be a solution to *avoid unnecessary postbacks for work that can be done at the client side in the same page*. However, if you need a redirection, the update panel would not be of much use because you load a new page.

Comment: Would using the image buttons post-back url property be better than using a click event with a redirect?

Comment: PostbackURL still triggers a postback. The only way around this is an UpdatePanel or other Ajax approach because the page needs to reload.

Comment: I guess one thing that's confusing to me is I assumed, perhaps incorrectly, that when I used a master page, only the content would change, yet when when a button is clicked, it appears that everything on the page refreshes, not just the part in the contentPlaceHolder.  I am in the process of adding update panels to each child page.  I'll see if that helps.

Comment: The master page is used just for GUI design purposes. It replicates the master content for each child page. The update panel solution is as I described in the comment for your post.

Comment: Ok, in my master page, I placed a script manager directly under my form tag.  In the Page_Load of my master page, I also added ScriptManger1.RegisterAsynPostBackControl() for each of the five images buttons.  My child pages all have 2 contentPlaceHolders, one with the ID=Head and the other with ID=ContentPlaceHolder1.  Directly under the second place holder, on each page, I placed an UpdatePanel.  Directly beneath that I placed the ContentTemplate tag, with the page contents in between.  For each UpdatePanel I set the UpdateMode property to Conditional.  But the whole page is still refreshing.

Comment: When you navigate on a new page there will always be a postback. Update panel is used only for preventing postbacks in the same page. Check here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/262368/How-to-Prevent-Postback-while-using-Response-Redir